# payPal REST-API makePaymentUsingCC error

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

After cloning rest-api-sample-app-php and updating for my environment (db, client, secret, etc...) I can buy a pizza using the paypal payment option.  I **cannot** using the *credit card option*, although I have a creditcard_id in the ppusers record.

The error happens in function `makePaymentUsingCC($creditCardId, $total, $currency, $payment_desc)`

I'm getting to makePaymentUsingCC and I can echo the params.  This line fails (for lack of a better word) :  `$ccToken = new CreditCardToken();`  I don't think the use statement `use PayPal\Api\CreditCardToken;` is finding the the file.

My main issue is not the pizza app, but my custom app is failing at the same point.  So, if we can figure out the pizza app issue it will probably resolve mine too.

Oh, the error message from the pizza app screen is:

> INVALID_RESOURCE_ID : The requested resource ID was not found

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any guidance on this issue?  I've yet to resolve it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any guidance on this issue? I've yet to resolve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A CreditCardToken is a reference to a tokenized credit card - essentially storing a card to re-use later without reentry, see https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card

If you have stored a credit card in the vault, you can then use it for subsequent payments.  If the credit card token used is not valid for your credentials then a INVALID_RESOURCE_ID is returned.

Comment: Hmmm, I did not get an email notification of your answer texswede. The error occurs in the api as it tries to instantiate a new CreditCardToken.  This is even before it tries to use it, so at this point we don't know if it is invalid or not.